# How To Fix UI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like my UI to be like the first picture, but when I expand it, it turns out like the second picture. How can I fix this?

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

Comment: Fix your anchors?

Answer (score 0):

Under your UI Canvas go to Canvas>Render Mode> and change from Screen Space Overlay to Screen Space Camera

Answer (score 0):

I set my aspect ratio to a fixed one (16:9) and changed the UI Scale Mode to scale with screen size, the match slider below (for resolution) to .5, which seemed to do the trick